# unable to impute missing values with below code

Tags: python, dataframe, imputation

I am using below code to impute missing values in df dataframe from pricer_df data frame

```py
df[df['PRICER_GROUP'].isnull()]['PRICER_GROUP'] = pricer_df['PRICER_GROUP']
```

this code is running fine but when I check by df data frame it still have same number of NAN values

Answer (score 0):

Pandas boolean indexing returns copy of dataframe, so your changes doesn't affect original dataframe. You can try

```py
df.loc[df['PRICER_GROUP'].isnull(), 'PRICER_GROUP'] = pricer_df['PRICER_GROUP']
```